# Qt SUBDIRS project not finding executable to debug

Tags: qt, directory, project, projects-and-solutions, subdirectory

I've decided to move all my projects (multiple DLLs and an executable) into a SUBDIRS project to make building easier. While this has let me build everything into a single folder, I can no longer debug from Qt Creator.

My folder structure is as follows:

```
Solution.pro
    \MyDLL1
    \MyDLL2
    \MyDLL3
    \MyDLL4
    \MyExecutable
    \OUT
```

I have all DLLs and my exe building into OUT (via DESTDIR in each project's .pro) - same level as the subdirs .pro. When attempting to debug, I get the following:

```
No executable specified.
Debugging has finished
```

I've tried modifying the project Run settings to directly point to \OUT\MyExecutable.exe, I've tried adding a DESTDIR to solution.pro pointing to OUT, but nothing so far as worked.

Is my setup completely wrong? Or am I missing one small piece to let Qt run the .exe to debug?

Edit:
I tried filling out my Run settings again: here is my Run setup via the Projects options, and the resulting message. The exe never actually gets launched. I am, however, able to Run the project with this setup, just not debug. I have verified the exe is not being launched by putting a breakpoint at the start of int main() within main.cpp in the executable's project. [image],

```
Debugging starts
Debugging has finished
```

Comment: So you have tried placing an absolute path into this setup http://doc.qt.nokia.com/qtcreator-2.5/creator-run-settings.html#specifying-a-custom-executable-to-run to an existing executable, right?

Comment: I have - in that case, the debugger states debugging has started, then immediately says it has finished. The exe never actually gets launched.

Comment: @Luca Carlon Added my Run setup for reference. When I have this defined, I can run the .exe via Qt, but debugging results in the Debugger thinking it started, then immediately stopped.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears updating Qt (both the Creator and Compiler) has resolved this issue.